# should client (javascript application) request for GET list after create or update a record?

Tags: javascript, php, rest, client-server, restful-architecture

when in a javascript application you update a record or create a new record,
do you need to request GET list of records again after request success ? 
or it's ok to get response from server and add it to local data ?

I'm using angular as my client side javascript framework.

Comment: I would suggest you to return a boolean when updating and the key of the created object or the full object when creating. This way you don't need to make an additional request to get all the records

Comment: what is this boolean value ?
can you explain in detail ?

Comment: `true` if the action worked well, `false` is there was a problem

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to do it.You can handle GUI data as per your Create or Update request result eg. If you update request returning 200OK from your server side then you can update GUI entry accordingly for that object. In case of failure or error message just keep the old entry and display the error message.

Comment: what if in another session, another record is created and we're not showing it.
Is that OK ?